# JS remove event listener from class instances

Tags: javascript, class

I'm trying to remove an event listener from my class instance. I would like to create multiple instances from the 'Person' class. Each instance needs to have a listener that will listen to a button press (Speak). I can't figure out how to remove the instances that was previously added. See my code below for more information.

```
class Person {

    constructor(name) {

        this.name = name; 
        this.createEventListeners();
    }

    createEventListeners() {

        this.speakButton = document.getElementById('speak');
        this.speakButton.addEventListener('click', this.speak.bind(this));
    }

    speak() {
        console.log(this.name + " says hi!")
    }

    destroy() {

        this.speakButton.removeEventListener('click', this.speak);
    }
}


const person1 = new Person('Sylvester');
const person2 = new Person('Arnold');
person2.destroy();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/av56q7mo/3/

Comment: you need a ref to `this.speak.bind(this)` to pass to destroy(), it has to be the exact same function, and bind() always produces a new function.

Comment: besides each new instance of person need to have its own button, I see all of them listen to the same button!!, or that's what you want? correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @SaymoinSam yes, this would be the most ideal situation

Comment: @dandavis Thank you, it works. https://jsfiddle.net/av56q7mo/4/

Answer (score 1):

Ok so why are declaring that button DOM element each time, and you can use arrow functions to keep the value of **this** so I have changed your code like this:

```js
var speakButton = document.getElementById('speak');
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name; 
    this.createEventListeners();
  }
    
  createEventListeners = _=>       
    speakButton.addEventListener('click', this.speak);
    
  speak = _=>
    console.log(this.name + " says hi!");
    
  destroy = _=>
    speakButton.removeEventListener("click", this.speak);
}

const person1 = new Person('Sylvester');
const person2 = new Person('Arnold');
person2.destroy();
```

```html
<button id="speak">Speak</button>
```